# What is Bottomsheetbehavior savedstate for?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I was looking at the bottom sheet behaviors and how to make it's state persists through destruction.
I found this class SavedState https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.SavedState

but I could not find any example on how to use that.
Moreover, handling state persistence can just be handled through the bundle

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putInt(Key, BottomSheetBehavior.from(yourscrollview).state)
}

private fun loadSavedInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    BottomSheetBehavior.from(yourscrollview).state = savedInstanceState.getInt(Key)
}
```

So what is that SavedState's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a configuration change such as screen rotation the activity is recreated.

In this recreation, the application gets restarted and may lose data in the views if not handled.

For do this there are two methods that are triggered at different stages of the lifecycle:

- onSaveInstanceState
- onRestoreInstanceState

They are used to save and retrieve values. The values are stored in the form of a key-value pair.

In your case:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {               
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putInt(key, state);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    int state = savedInstanceState.getInt(key);
}
```